# How to get the size and duration of an mp3 file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to calculate the total length of an mp3 file.

Currently I am using a PHP class which I found @ http://www.zedwood.com/article/php-calculate-duration-of-mp3.

This is working perfectly if the mp3 file in same server.

but if I have a URL from other site it throwing error. Please help me.

Is there any JavaScript J-Query function to get the length of the mp3 file

```
<?php include("mp3.class.php");
$f = 'http://cdn.enjoypur.vc/upload_file/5570/5738/5739/7924/Blue%20Eyes%20-%20Yo%20Yo%20Honey%20Singh%20(PagalWorld.com)%20-192Kbps%20.mp3';
$m = new mp3file($f);
$a = $m->get_metadata();

if ($a['Encoding']=='Unknown')
    echo "?";
else if ($a['Encoding']=='VBR')
    print_r($a);
else if ($a['Encoding']=='CBR')
    print_r($a);
unset($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can get mp3 duration using Web Audio API:

```js
const mp3file = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/media-sample-files/master/doorbell.mp3'
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
request.open('GET', mp3file, true)
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer'
request.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response,
        function(buffer) {
            let duration = buffer.duration
            console.log(duration)
            document.write(duration)
        }
    )
}
request.send()
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the simplest solution is to use the audio html element to get the time duration and to obtain the size directly from the file returned by the FileReader object. A code example of this approach is shown below.

One down side of this and all the other solutions presented so far is the 10-20 second delay it takes for the audio tag's durationchanged event to fire when loading large, eg > 200MB files. Clearly there is a faster way to get this info because the duration is shown immediately when the file is entered into the browser as a file:///.... URL.

```
function checkMp3SizeAndDuration()
{    
    var files = document.getElementById('upload-file').files;
    var file = files[0];
    if (file.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        audio.src = e.target.result
        audio.addEventListener('durationchange', function() {
            console.log("durationchange: " + audio.duration);
        },false);

        audio.addEventListener('onerror', function() {
            alert("Cannot get duration of this file.");
        }, false);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a library that can run at client-side, attempting to fetch just enough of the MP3 to read the ID3 tags:

http://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader

or

Try

HTML File API.

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/09/23/getting-audio-file-information-with-htmls-file-api-and-audio-element/

Comment: The duration of an MP3 file is more often than not stored in the ID3 tag and has to be calculated by scanning through all the audio frames.

Answer (score 2):

Having not been able to find something that was fast and didn't require a bunch of extra boilerplate code, I tweaked an existing server side javascript utility to run directly in the browser. Demo code is available at: https://github.com/eric-gilbertson/fast-mp3-duration

Comment: is there a quick solution for wav possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getID3()` PHP library that works for VBR files as well.

This link help you **[sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/1.9.7/)**.

It's very much active in development.

Answer (score 0):

**A Famous and Very SPI that you can use [MP3 SPI](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html)
and the code is also very simple**

```
File file = new File("filename.mp3");
AudioFileFormat baseFileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
Map properties = baseFileFormat.properties();
Long duration = (Long) properties.get("duration");
```