# Run a function inside of another function based on some situation

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function to combine natural human recorded voice with speech synthesis in a very simple way, here is the code:

```js
function speak(text, type){

   switch(type){
    
    case 'answer':
    
    // Initiate Speech Synthesis
    speech('This is the Answer');

    // After Speech Synthesis has finished
    playVoice('voice_1.mp3');

    break;

   }

}


function speech(input){

  // Fetch the available voices.
  const voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(voice => voice.lang == 'en-US'); 
  
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voice = voice[0];

  // Set the text.
  msg.text = input;

  // Queue this utterance.
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  
  // Track if Speech Synthesis has finished
  msg.onend = function(event) {
  console.log('Speech has finished being spoken after ' + event.elapsedTime + ' milliseconds.');
  }

}
```

So I want to run speech synthesis then after Speech Synthesis has finished in `speech` function, I want to play audio that is in `speak` function here:

```
// After Speech Synthesis has finished
playVoice('voice_1.mp3');
```

Guys, please tell me if there is any solution to do this that I'm missing?

What would you do if you were me?

Note: I want many different behaviors from `speak` function and it makes it confusing how I want to deal with my issue:

```
    function speak(text, type){

       switch(type){

        case 'answer':

        // Initiate Speech Synthesis
        speech('This is the Answer');

        // After Speech Synthesis has finished
        playVoice('voice_1.mp3');

        break;

        case 'question':

        // Play an specific voice
        playVoice('voice_2.mp3');

        // Then Talk the text
        speech('This is the Question');

        // After Speech Synthesis has finished
        playVoice('voice_3.mp3');

        break;

       }
}
```

Comment: I'd definitely go for `Promise`s

Comment: Now I'm searching for what `Promise` is ...

Comment: What is your question exactly?  Are you asking how to play mp3 files or?

Comment: The desired behavior seems unclear. Can you clarify exactly what's supposed to happen? Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at Codepen. the desired behavior is right after Speech Synthesis has finished (I track this in line 51) I want to execute `playVoice(value);` at line 17... The value is provided by the `resolve('voice_1.mp3'); ` which is in line 54.

Comment: Your `Promise` implementation was wrong. Check [this](https://codepen.io/3ldar/pen/JjoOGmW?editors=0011)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pass the mp3's filename to the "speech" function as a parameter, and call it on the "onend" function? Like this?

```
function speak(text, type){

    switch(type){

        case 'answer':

            // Initiate Speech Synthesis & voice to play when done
            speech('This is the Answer', 'voice_1.mp3');

            break;

        case 'question':

            // Play an specific voice
            playVoice('voice_2.mp3');

            // Then Talk the text & voice to play when done
            speech('This is the Question', 'voice_3.mp3');

            break;

    }
}


function speech(input,voiceToPlay){

    // Fetch the available voices.
    const voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(voice => voice.lang == 'en-US'); 

    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    msg.voice = voice[0];

    // Set the text.
    msg.text = input;

    // Queue this utterance.
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

    // After Speech Synthesis has finished
    msg.onend = function(event) {
        console.log('Speech has finished being spoken after ' + event.elapsedTime + ' milliseconds.');
        if(voiceToPlay) {
            console.log('Play voice.');
            playVoice(voiceToPlay);
        }
    }

}
```

As for the question's case, where you have an mp3 file playing before and after your speech synthesis, I'd consider something along the lines [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771845/how-to-get-the-size-and-duration-of-an-mp3-file) to check what the duration of what the mp3 file is, and then use setTimeout for that length of time before executing the speech() function. I'm sure you can write a function that takes the audio file's path that you're passing to the "speech" function, do a look-up, and then return the duration in ms in a variable.

[Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/TessaWatkins/pen/abzVNoW?editors=0010) I forked from yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wanted! After Start appears you have 2 seconds to click on anywhere on the page to play the speech synthesis...

```js
console.log('Start')

setTimeout(function(){
  
let promise;
  
speak('this is a text', 'answer');
  
function speak(text, type){

   switch(type){
    
    case 'answer':
    
    // Initiate Speech Synthesis
    speech('This is the Answer');
    // After Speech Synthesis has finished
    onSpeechEnd()

    break;
       
    case 'question':

    // Play an specific voice
     playVoice('voice_2.mp3');

    // Then Talk the text
     speech('This is the Question');  

   }
  
  
   async function onSpeechEnd() {
 
      let result = await promise;
      playVoice(result)
    
   }
  
} 
   // Function
  function speech(input){
    
  // Fetch the available voices.
  const voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(voice => voice.lang == 'en-US'); 
  
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  msg.voice = voice[0];

  // Set the text.
  msg.text = input;

  // Queue this utterance.
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
  
  // Track if Speech Synthesis has finished
  promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  msg.onend = function(event) {
  console.log('Speech has finished being spoken');
  resolve('voice_1.mp3');
  }
      
  });
       
  }
                      
},2000)

function playVoice(voice){
  console.log(voice)
}
```