# Calculate duration of ArrayBuffer without Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I have an app that uses XHR to download audio data from a remote location and save it as an array buffer locally locally, similar to the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771845/how-to-get-the-size-and-duration-of-an-mp3-file) or [here](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1036/how-to-retrieve-the-duration-of-a-mp3-wav-audio-file-in-the-browser-with-javascript). This approach works well, but requires execution in a UI context for the `Audio` element to be available. Is there an alternative approach to calculating duration of `ArrayBuffer`, ideally in a WebWorker/ ServiceWorker context?

The current approach uses `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` to decode the audio binary, but this is not available in a WebWorker context. The `ArrayBuffer` is not necessarily in a single format or codec and has not yet been encoded.

Answer (score 3):

If your `ArrayBuffer` contains decoded PCM audio, you could use `getAudioDuration()` below. You may wish to directly pass `bytesPerSample` if that conditional doesn't encapsulate your decoded audio.

```
function getAudioDuration(arrayBuffer, numChannels, sampleRate, isFloatingPoint) {
  // PCM 16 or Float32
  const bytesPerSample = (isFloatingPoint ? Float32Array : Uint16Array).BYTES_PER_ELEMENT

  // total samples/frames
  const totalSamples = arrayBuffer.byteLength / bytesPerSample / numChannels 

  // total seconds
  return totalSamples / sampleRate
}
```

If your `ArrayBuffer` contains encoded audio (Opus, MP3, WAV), you could either manually parse the binary byte headers, use a third-party library to parse the headers, or have your server send you the audio properties (channels, sample rate, etc) via HTTP response headers.

Comment: This approach looks simple, but my next concern would be how to calculate "numChannels" and "sampleRate" for an arbitrary audio binary? For my use case, I don't have control over the audio format for encoding.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question and assumed you had decoded PCM audio.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: This works nicely (for my case, with 16-bit PCM audio), but worth noting that rather than `arrayBuffer.byteLength`, you should use `(arrayBuffer.byteLength - 44)`, since WAV files typically have a 44-byte header. (though the header [can be longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991405/how-can-i-detect-whether-a-wav-file-has-a-44-or-46-byte-header))